# Obtaining a plan of the Cemetery in Paterna near Valencia, Spain

Tags: spain

Using this [website](https://www.paterna.es/es/areas-gestion-municipal/infraestructura-medio-ambiente/cementerio.html) I am able to retrieve information about the burials at the Cemetery of Paterna, Spain.

- Grandfather: Enrique Torres Dominguez:

[image: Granddad]

- Grandmother: Patrocinio Marcilla Bienzobas

[image: Grandmother]

They have actually transcribed my Grandmothers second surname incorrectly.

As you can see, they are both in the same location:

> - Cuadro (Quarter ?): 3
> - Bloque (Block ?): 7
> - Altura (Row / Level ?): 1
> - Numero (Number): 380

I have actually visited their grave a number of times when visiting Spain and was actually at the Burial at the Church when I attended with my mother back when I was 11.

Gravestone:

[image: Photo of Gravestone]

I can see from the website that the address for contact is:

> Ayuntamiento de Paterna
> Plaza Ingeniero Castells, nº 1
> 46980 Paterna (Valencia)

I am trying to see if I can obtain a plan of the cemetery showing this location of my Grandparents gravestone. Is my only option to write a letter to this address? Or is there another way to obtain this?

---

### Update

I did find the cemetery on the [Find A Grave](https://www.findagrave.com/cemetery/1772852/cementerio-de-paterna) website but it had no map. So I have written to them. And it is on [Google Maps](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/Cementerio+Municipal+Paterna/@39.5106218,-0.439978,18.5z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0xd6045375fb74ed1:0xe872f3c992adf236!8m2!3d39.5100896!4d-0.4409105):

[image: Google Maps]

Comment: I would suggest calling to the phone number they show in the site. You may reach someone that will be able to explain further in an informal context of a call, rather than in an email

Comment: @fedorqui I feel obliged to be fluent enough in Spanish to phone them though. But we'll see.

Answer (score 2):

In Spain the local cemeteries are administered by the local council. Each town hall has an architect who is responsible for all mapping of the area. He is probably your best port of call. This is the website for Paterna Ayuntamiento [website](https://www.paterna.es/es/) and as this is on the outskirts of Valencia city I am sure you will find that someone there will help. An alternative is an email in English (rather than Google Spanish) will, in my experience, get you a suitable reply.

Comment: Thank you. I will contact them. Note that I ways write (whether letter or email) in both English and the DeepL Spanish so that they have both.